# table.insert is not adding the parameter Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I made this little animation handler code, and I want to add the animation grid name, defined in a function, to another table (grids, which is inside a table called sprite), but when I try to insert the new grid into the `sprites.grids` table it does not work and the code crashes at `anim8.newAnimation(grid('1-'...` sattin that I gave a nil grid. I don't understand. :( Code:

```
require("table")

function createSprite(x, y, path)
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")
    local sprite = {
        position = {
            x = x,
            y = y
        },
        sprite = love.graphics.newImage(path),
        currentAnimation,
        animations,
        grids = {}
    }

    function sprite:createSpriteGrid(animation, maxFrames)
        animation = anim8.newGrid(self.sprite:getWidth() / maxFrames, self.sprite:getHeight(), self.sprite:getWidth(), self.sprite:getHeight())
        table.insert(self.grids, animation)
    end

    function sprite:setAnimation(grid, maxFrames, time)
        self.currentAnimation = anim8.newAnimation(grid('1-'.. maxFrames .. '', 1), time)
    end

    function sprite:update(dt)
        self.currentAnimation:update(dt)
    end

    function sprite:draw(scale)
        self.currentAnimation:draw(self.sprite, self.position.x, self.position.y, nil, scale)
    end

    return sprite
end

shop = createSprite(630, 160, "assets/shop.png")
shop:createSpriteGrid(shopAnim, 6)
shop:setAnimation(shop.grids.shopAnim, 6, 0.17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially that function is most likely not doing what you want:

```lua
    function sprite:createSpriteGrid(animation, maxFrames)
        animation = anim8.newGrid(self.sprite:getWidth() / maxFrames, self.sprite:getHeight(), self.sprite:getWidth(), self.sprite:getHeight())
        table.insert(self.grids, animation)
    end
```

In words: you pass `animation` and `maxFrames`, but never use `animation` and immediately replace it with your grid. Then you add your grid to the `self.grids` array, and since its the first entry it will get the index/key `1`. Therefore `shop.grids.shopAnim` is nil, because you never set it. `shop.grids[1]` would work.